# Função de soma com um valor grande retorna um resultado errado

Tags: javascript, funções, característica-linguagem, inteiros

Por que minha função de soma está me retornando `633223344234234200000` e não `633223344234234234235`?

```js
function plus(n) {
    return n+1;
}

console.log(plus(633223344234234234234))
```

Comment: Devido à quantidade de algarismos significativos máxima que o tipo de dados pode armazenar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Em *JavaScript* o tipo default para se trabalhar com números é o [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) que representa um valor em ponto flutuante de dupla precisão(64 bits) seguindo a norma [IEEE 754](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).

Conforme a norma IEEE 754 só podem ser representados com segurança números entre`-(2^53 - 1)` e `2^53 - 1`. Esses limites podem ser verificados através das constantes:

- [Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER), para o limite superior, que tem o valor de `9007199254740991`.
- [Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MIN_SAFE_INTEGER) para o limite inferior, com o valor de `-9007199254740991`.

Para conseguir trabalhar com números para além dos limites de segurança numéricos estabelecidos com `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` e  `Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER`, em *Javascript* usa-se o tipo [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt).

Um `BigInt` é criado com o acréscimo do sufixo `n` ao final de um inteiro literal ou chamando a função `BigInt()`.

`BigInt` não podem ser usado com métodos no objeto [`Math`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math) e não pode ser misturado em operações com instâncias de `Number`.

```js
function plus(n) {
  //Caso n seja BigInt realiza a soma com parcelas do tipo BigInt 
  //usando a função BigInt() senão realiza a operação padrão.
  return n + (typeof(n) == `bigint` ? BigInt("1") : 1);
}

// Tentativa de gerar um inteiro maior que Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
let normal = 633223344234234234235;

// Gerando um inteiro de tamanho arbitrário usando o sufixo n
let big = 633223344234234234235n;

console.log(`Utilizando inteiros convencionais ${plus(normal)}`);

console.log(`Utilizando inteiros arbitrários ${plus(big)}`);
```

Answer (score 8):

Acontece que em JavaScript um número é representado como `Number`. De acordo com a [especificação](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-language-types-number-type) (em tradução livre):

> O tipo Number tem exatamente 18437736874454810627 (ou seja,
>   2<sup>64</sup> - 2<sup>53</sup> + 3) valores, representando os valores
>   IEEE 754-2008 de precisão dupla no formato 64 bits, conforme
>   especificado no Padrão IEEE para aritmética de ponto flutuante binário
>   (...)

Sabendo que um número é representado como `Number`, você pode dar uma olhada no `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`. E, de acordo com a [documentação do MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER), "*Safe*, neste contexto, refere-se à capacidade de representar números inteiros exatamente e compará-los corretamente.". Veja:

```js
console.log(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)
console.log(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 1)
console.log(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 2)
console.log(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 1 === Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 2)
```

Ok, agora que já entendemos sobre o "limite", o que acontece no seu caso é um "arredondamento". Caso precise realizar essa operação, você pode usar o [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt):

```js
function plus(n) {
  return BigInt(n) + BigInt(1);
}

const soma = plus('633223344234234234234');
console.log(soma.toString());
```

Note que é preciso passar o valor "grande" como `String` para o `BigInt`, pois se usarmos ele como número (`BigInt(633223344234234234234)`), estaremos na verdade passando um valor arredondado.